# Keyframe Transform Problem

Tags: animation, keyframes

Hello I'm making a rifle reload animation, so when my animation ends, my rifle should go default transform but when i copy first keyframe and paste as a last keyframe, i see they are not same transform. What are the possible reasons?

Comment: because https://www.mic.com/articles/147150/physicists-have-new-proof-that-backward-time-travel-is-impossible or because the first keyframe does not cover all the transform/op/axis that have been transformed in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first frame, have you keyed all your selected channels with 'i' pressed -> Location/Rotation or whatever transform you are animating?